# Data type error using case statement from Varchar(Max) source

Tags: t-sql, sqldatatypes

I have a table with data that ranges thru these values.

```
-0.0011086463928222656, 
0, 
9.318138472735882e-5, 
NA
```

The data type of the source is VARCHAR(MAX).

I am developing the `SELECT` statement below, to insert into another staging table for obvious reasons.

```
SELECT  CASE
            WHEN air_wpa = 'NA' THEN 0.0
            WHEN air_wpa = 0.0 THEN 0.00
            ELSE CONVERT(NUMERIC(18, 9), air_wpa)
        END AS air_wpa
FROM    Table
```

I get this error.

```
Error converting data type varchar to numeric.
```

Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

When you compare `air_wpa = 0.0` in the `CASE` expression, the [Data type precedence](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/data-type-precedence-transact-sql) rules are applied, which say that when comparing a `varchar` column with a `decimal` constant, all values in the column (except those that match the first `WHEN` clause) are converted to the `decimal` data type to perform the comparison.

To avoid that conversion, use a `varchar` constant in the comparison. Additionally, if you use SQL Server 2012 or later, you can use `TRY_CONVERT` to get a `NULL` value (instead of an error) when you encounter a value which cannot be converted to `NUMERIC(18,9)`.

```
SELECT  CASE
            WHEN air_wpa = 'NA' THEN 0.0
            WHEN air_wpa = '0.0' THEN 0.00
            ELSE TRY_CONVERT(NUMERIC(18, 9), air_wpa)
        END 'air_wpa'
FROM    TheTable
```

Comment: Yes.  Amazing response.  I knew there was a precedent issue but it wasn't coming to me.  Thanks a lot.